# get parent key from array php foreach

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array $arr:

```
 Array
(
[2] => Array
    (
        [status] => 0
        [item] => Food Processer
        [catagory] => Appliance
    )

[23] => Array
    (
        [status] => 1
        [item] => 12 cup medium muffin tray
        [catagory] => Kitchenware
    )

[24] => Array
    (
        [status] => 1
        [item] => 24 cup mini muffin tray
        [catagory] => Kitchenware
    ) etc...
```

i would like to end up with a table row for each element:

```
<tr id="2" class="0"><td>Food Processer</td><td>Appliance</td></tr>
```

my current code is:

```
foreach ($arr as $a)
    {
    echo('<tr  id="'.key($a).'" class="'.$a['status'].'">');
        echo('<td>');
        echo($a['item']);
        echo('</td>');
        echo('<td>');
        echo($a['catagory']);
        echo('</td>');  

        echo('</tr>');
    }
```

but i am getting the status key (string 'status') as the id  value how can i get the parent $arr key ie(2,23,24).

Comment: You nee to do foreach($array as $key => $value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a variable for your id in the foreach:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $data) {
    echo('<tr  id="'.$key.'" class="'.$data['status'].'">');
    echo('<td>');
    echo($data['item']);
    echo('</td>');
    echo('<td>');
    echo($data['catagory']);
    echo('</td>');
    echo('</tr>');
}
```

Comment: thanks i never really got the as $key => $value before i will mark as answered as soon as the site allows me

Answer (score 0):

normally like so:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$element) {...}
```

`$key` should be the numbers you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
Array
(
[2] => Array
    (
        [status] => 0
        [item] => Food Processor
        [category] => Appliance
    )
}
```

(spelling)

```
foreach ($arr as $key=>$a){

    // $a['status'] will be 0
    // $a['item'] will be 'Food Processor'
    // $a['category'] will be 'Appliance'
    // $key will be 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

echo "key: {$key} --- value: {$value}";

}
```